# Which material gives the best compression stressability per weight for a 1000x30mm tube?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am building a lightweight tube construction with tubes and connectors.

Some tubes resist bending forces, and I am using unidirectional carbon fiber composite for those. Works great.

Now I am adding some tubes that must resist compression. CFK seems to shine a bit less for that- aluminum seems almost as good, and I was unable to determine a reliable formula for CFK seems it doesn't really seem to conform to Euler.

Which material should I use?

Comment: There are material tables in many textbooks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

The materials in those tables varies widely- I am asking here so I (and others) don't have to buy a lot of textbooks and compile a list.

Comment: Maybe don't tunnel vision on *one* material but also consider construction and multiple materials working together. There's a reason spars made of multiple materials and are foam cored and wrapped. A thin material on its own will be prone to buckling, regardless of material strength, whereas a weaker material that requires you to use more of it anyways and is therefore thicker may not be. Strength is not just about material (emphasis on the singular).